# datediff....does not make sense

Tags: reporting-services, datediff

Below is my data, I'm trying to get the deference between 2 dates (Punch in and schedule in) to create a report for employees who comes early to work.

I used the following code in expression but the results is way off! Can any one help?

Could it be the formatting of date?

```
=DateDiff("h", Fields!Scheduled_In.Value, Fields!Punched_In.Value) 
    & ":" & DateDiff("n", Fields!Scheduled_In.Value, Fields!Punched_In.Value) mod 60
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how or why you are getting those results, unless you datetime is actually a string that is being converted.

Anyway, I reproduced your data using a standard datetime format, here's the dataset query with the sample data in.

```
DECLARE @t table (ANumber int identity(1,1), Scheduled_In datetime, Punched_In datetime)
INSERT INTO @t (Scheduled_In, Punched_In) VALUES 
('2022-05-30 09:45:00', '2022-05-30 10:04:48'),
('2022-05-30 12:00:00', '2022-05-30 11:46:09'),
('2022-05-30 14:00:00', '2022-05-30 13:56:44'),
('2022-05-30 14:00:00', '2022-05-30 14:01:30'),
('2022-05-30 09:45:00', '2022-05-30 09:21:11'),
('2022-05-30 09:45:00', '2022-05-30 09:57:18'),
('2022-05-30 14:00:00', '2022-05-30 13:55:37')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then used your original expression which actually works as I expected although the results are probably not what you want.

I then added a new column and used the following expression.

```
=DATEADD(
        DateInterval.Second, 
        ABS(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second , Fields!Scheduled_In.Value, Fields!Punched_In.Value)),
        DateSerial(2000, 01, 01)
        )
```

What this does workout the absolute difference in seconds between the two fields.
It then adds this number of seconds to a fixed date (2020-01-01 although the date used does not matter).

So if the difference was say 1 hour and 5 minutes and 15 seconds the result would give us 2020-01-01 01:05:15

Then I changed the format expression of the textbox to this..

```
=IIF(
    DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Second, Fields!Scheduled_In.Value, Fields!Punched_In.Value) > 0
    , " - "
    , " + "
    ) & "HH:mm:ss"
```

All this does is start with a `+` or `-` depending on if the scheduled time is earlier or later then the punched time, followed by a standard time format string. Basically it hides the date portion and puts +/- in front of the time.

**Note** This will not give the correct results if there is more than 24 hours between the times.

here's the result

[image]